# Use a index and column from one lookup dataframe to create a new column in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for looking up values:

```
ruralw2 = [[0.1,0.3,0.5], [0.1,0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.2,0.7], [0.1,0,0.3]] 
rw2 = pd.DataFrame(data=ruralw2, columns=['city','suburbs','rural'],index=['low','med','high','v-high'])
```

[image]

and then I have a another dataframe where I want to get 'p' values based on data in rw2 dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['location','income','p'])
df['location'] = ['city','city','suburbs','rural','rural']
df['income'] = ['low','med','high','v-high','med']
```

[image]

What I expect is this:

[image]

It's possible to use for loop but its an antipattern in Pandas and I think there should be a better way.

```
for i in np.arange(df.shape[0]):
    df['p'][i] = rw2.loc[df['income'][i],df['location'][i]]
```

Another possibility is to write very long np.where(... logic but it doesn't feel right either and it wouldn't be very scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `stack` on `rw2` and `reindex` with both columns income and location of `df` like:

```
df['p'] = rw2.stack().reindex(df[['income', 'location']]).to_numpy()
  location  income    p
0     city     low  0.1
1     city     med  0.1
2  suburbs    high  0.2
3    rural  v-high  0.3
4    rural     med  0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reset_index` to bring the income values into the data frame, followed by `pd.melt` to restructure it in your result format. You can then merge this new data frame with `df`

Step 1:

```
rw2_reset = rw2.reset_index()
rw2_reset
```

[image]

Step2:

```
rw2_melt = pd.melt(rw2_reset, id_vars='index', value_vars=['city', 'suburbs', 'rural'])
rw2_melt.rename(columns={'index':'income', 'variable':'location','value':'p'}, inplace=True)
rw2_melt
```

[image]

Step3:

```
result = pd.merge(df, rw2_melt, on=['location', 'income'], how='left').drop(columns='p_x').rename(columns={'p_y':'p'})
result
```

[image]